# MongoDB 2.4 Replica set with authorization

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

How to set up proper authorization for mongodb 2.4.1.
My setup seem to be not working.
Replica members config:

```
dbpath = /vol/data/mongodb/

# logfile
logpath   = /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend = true

# socket
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27018

# replication
replSet = <%= hostname[14,4] %>

# authentication
keyFile = /etc/mongodb.pass

# turn off legacy privilege mode
setParameter = supportCompatibilityFormPrivilegeDocuments=false
setParameter = textSearchEnabled=false

# turn off authorization
auth = true
```

After adding user authorization:

```
> use admin
> db.addUser( { user: "admin", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )
```

I can't access to rs.* commands.

```
> use admin
> db.auth('admin','xxx')
1
> rs.status()
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }
```

Comment: Got it - I shoud give "clusterAdmin" rights to user in order to access rs.* commands

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#clusterAdmin

Comment: update to your link, since it rotted: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

Answer (score 3):

I too was dealing with the same sort of problem.I have a solution for it.

**Turn off auth**

1.Create a user with root privilege

`Root privilege yields readWrite access to database while userAdminAnyDatabase role doesn't.`

```
use admin
db.createUser( {
    user: "root",
    pwd: "pass",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  });
```

**Turn on auth**

2.Login with the root user

```
mongo -u root --authenticationDatabase admin -p
```

Then you can execute your commands.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a keyFile if you have a replicaset.

Taken from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/  :

> Enable authentication using the auth or keyFile settings. Use auth for standalone instances, and keyFile with replica sets and sharded clusters. keyFile implies auth and allows members of a MongoDB deployment to authenticate internally.